# Remove trailing comma of macro expansion

Tags: c++, c, gcc, preprocessor

I have a 'system' to generate classes using macros (there is unfortunately no other way).

In some cases, for example for an initializer list, this leads to a trailing comma
that I'd like to get rid of:

```
#define REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA(...) ?what to put here?
#define FOO a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h,

REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA(FOO) --> expands to a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h
```

If it just removes the last argument that would be fine too, of course.
Aka if `REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA(a, b, c)` expands to `a, b`.

The macro will always get at least two arguments, so the minimal case
would be: `REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA(a,)` --> expands to `a`.

Is this even possible? I searched for a few hours with Google, but
nothing comes up.

Comment: That's a problem to solve in the generator, not with corrections for the generated code.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/C-C-plus-plus/preprocessor/macros/__VA_ARGS__/count-arguments) helps... I haven't tried to write a solution to your problem.

Comment: why FOO do even exist in that form?

Comment: @pmg It did... I wrote https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/macro_args.h

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be nice to use `#define REMOVE_FIRST(a, ...) __VA_ARGS__`, but that would require reversing macro arguments order. I do not see a way to do it (other then overloading it anyway). So overload the macro on count of arguments and enumerate each overload to remove trailing argument:

```
// example macro overoad for up to 9 args
// TODO: write REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_{1,2,3,4,5....} for each case
#define REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_8(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8)  \
                                _1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7
#define REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_9(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9)  \
                                _1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8
#define REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_N(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,N,...)  \
        REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_##N
#define REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA(...)  \
        REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_N(__VA_ARGS__,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define FOO a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h,

REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA(FOO) --> expands to a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h
```

The following was added by Carlo Wood:

Thanks! I wrote a small program to generate the above, so it is
easy to increase the maximum number of arguments that this still works with:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string args1_N(int n)
{
  std::ostringstream ss;
  char const* prefix = "_";
  for (int a = 1; a <= n; ++a)
  {
    ss << prefix << a;
    prefix = ",_";
  }
  return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
  int const max_args = 9;

  for (int n = 1; n <= max_args + 1; ++n)
    std::cout << "#define REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_" << n << "(" << args1_N(n) <<
      ") \\\n                                " << args1_N(n - 1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "#define REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_N(" << args1_N(max_args + 1) << ",N,...) \\\n" <<
    "        REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_##N\n";
  std::cout << "#define REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA(...) \\\n" <<
    "        REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_N(__VA_ARGS__";
  for (int a = max_args + 1; a > 0; --a)
    std::cout << "," << a;
  std::cout << ")(__VA_ARGS__)" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was writing my own solution in the mean time using pmg's link and made https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/macro_args.h Seems to use the same idea, no?

Comment: `eems to use the same idea` yes

Comment: Not sure why you introduce `REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_IN`? It seems to work too when I just do `REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_IN(FOO)`

Comment: Och, right, it will work because `REMOVE_TRAILING_COMMA_N` does another level of expansion to expand the argument. I believe just convention, to have the macro argument fully expanded before the internal is called, but indeed it can be removed.

Comment: You could also use https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_REVERSE` and then use `#define REMOVE_FIRST(a, ...) __VA_ARGS__`. Or from P99 I see [P99_ALLBUTLAST](https://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__basic__list__operations_gab415521b8ae3750ab155359355f46165.html#gab415521b8ae3750ab155359355f46165)

Comment: It is not clear if P99 works for any number of arguments, or does it have a limit?

Comment: No idea - see the sources. not that hard to find: https://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/p99__generated_8h_a1d1df64eabc7e929e4d4c37f21f98557.html#a1d1df64eabc7e929e4d4c37f21f98557 `The following was added by Carlo Wood:` That's odd - I believe please post it as a separate answer next time.

Comment: It isn't a separate answer, just an extension to yours. Plus, I clearly added that that part is my responsibility - not yours :p.